# Alguien sabe como puedo programar 2 botones en una gridview?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net

mi problemas es que tengo un grilla que muestra una table de mi base de datos, hasta ahi bien, lo que me estan pidiendo es que el usuario en cuestion puedan cambiar el "estado" de una solicitud con el simple hecho de apretar un Boton el la Grilla

Este es el codigo del SQL:

`CREATE PROCEDURE ModificarSolicitudAnulada
    @codigo int
    as
    begin
    if NOT(EXISTS(Select * From Solicitud Where 
  codigo=@codigo))
            return -1

            UPDATE Solicitud
            set Solicitud.estado='Anulada'
            where Solicitud.codigo=@codigo
            IF(@@Error=0)
            RETURN 1
        ELSE
            RETURN -2
    End
    go`

No paso toda mi BD por que las tablas son muy largas, bien lo que hace el Procedimiento es cambiar el estado a "Anulado", quería saber como programo el botón cuando el usuario lo presiona. Como son 2 botones y no tengo mucha idea use el:

```
`if(gvsolicitud.SelectedIndex==0)`
```

Y que ejecute el código, pero luego me di cuenta que no es asi, lo que preciso es llamar al boton y ahi poner todo el código , pero no se como hacerlo

Codigo de lo que planeaba al apretar el boton :

```
protected void gvsolicitud_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            EntidadesCompartidas.Solicitud unS = Logica.LogicaSolicitud.ConsultaEstadoSolicitud(Convert.ToInt32(gvsolicitud.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text));

            if (unS != null)
            {
                List<EntidadesCompartidas.Solicitud> _lista = LogicaSolicitud.modificar(unS);

                gvsolicitud.DataSource = _lista;
                gvsolicitud.DataBind();
```

La celda 2 contiene el atributo codigo el cual uso en el procedimiento de la BD

Gracias por su tiempo .

[image: Grilla]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `GridView` tiene el evento `RowCommand` que puedes usar para defirenciar cada uno de los botones, pero para eso a cada boton le debes definir un `CommandName`

[CommandName Propiedad](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.commandname?view=netframework-4.8)

Entonces si al primer boton le defines `CommandName = "Anular"` y al segundo `CommandName = "Ejecutar"` podrias usar el evento

```
void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName=="Anular")
    {
        //codigo
    }

    if(e.CommandName=="Ejecutar")
    {
        //codigo
    }
}
```

De esta forma deferencias cada accion sobre la row del grid

[GridView.RowCommand Evento](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Muchas gracias !!